# C keyword identifier in lex

Tags: c, formatting, lex

I'm new to writing lex files and I'm not sure whether I'm formatting my file correctly.  I'm trying to capture C keywords from a C source file and print them back out with a format string prefixed.

My attempt is (showing a partial keyword list):

```
%%

auto|do|goto|short    printf("%s%s", "formatting", yytext);
```

In some examples I've looked at, the words in the first column are surrounded by double quotes. Is that necessary, or have I formatted my lex file correctly to capture the keywords I've listed?

That is, should I instead have written:

```
"auto"|"do"|"goto"|"short"    printf("%s%s", "formatting", yytext);
```

When are double quotes necessary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Double quotes are necessary when the pattern text includes a regular expression operator or whitespace. It's probably a good idea to use them whenever the pattern text does not consist solely of letters and digits.

In the case of a simple alphabetic keyword, they are clearly not necessary. It's also not necessary to use them if the pattern text is already escaped with a <kbd>\</kbd>, so you can write `\n` without quotes.

---

Actually, double quotes are not *necessary*. There are several ways of escaping characters, but double quotes have the advantage of being able to quote several consecutive characters. However, the following would be fine as well:

```
[a][u][t][o]|[d][o]...
```

which is sometimes used for manual case-insensitivity:

```
[aA][uU][tT][oO]|[dD][oO]...
```

Flex allows you to specify case-insensitivity for a pattern segment by using the flag syntax -- `(?i:auto|do|goto|short)` -- but that's a flex extension so you'll still see patterns like the above.

Comment: When I run my compiled lex program in terminal without using double quotes, an input of `auto` does prefix the formatting text.  If this is the case, why would double quotes be necessary?  Sorry, I'm still a bit confused as to when they are beneficial.

Comment: @victorBrunell: Suppose you wanted to recognize the token `auto*`. In that case, you would need to escape the `*`, because it's a regex operator. You could use `auto\*` or `auto[*]` but most of us would use `"auto*"`

Comment: @ rici Ah, got it.  So double quotes remove the effect of special regex characters?  Are there any that aren't affected by double quotes?

Comment: @victorBrunell: yep. Quote characters :) Also backslashes. Anything else inside double quotes is Just A Character.